# How to handle missing dependency for a Bean defined in a spring boot starter modular Gradle build?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

For this demo:

- I have a Bean defined in an `event-starter` module as a Spring Boot Starter that I want to consume in my application module: `application`. As far as I can tell, it has the right, albeit oversimplified, config in a `GreeterAutoConfiguration` file and `resources/META-INF/spring.factories`
- My `build.gradle` file in the `application` module pulls in `event-starter` as a dependency like so:

  ```
      implementation project(':event-starter')
  ```
- I'm using both `io.spring.dependency-management` and the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor` annotation processor.
- and my build compiles as I would expect it to.

However, when I actually *run* the application, the Bean I am pulling in from the starter module does not appear to be discoverable by the Spring IoC container, and I don't know why:

```
Field greeter in com.example.app.StarterApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.starter.Greeter' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.starter.Greeter' in your configuration.
```

I'm roughly using these two tutorials [[1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter), [2](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-starter/)] for development and here is a link to the breaking demo:

- https://github.com/Sideman4J/SpringStarterDemo

Any help to identify what's missing/wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your autoconfig class is not a `@Configuration` class, it's maybe not picked up as one, see https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-custom-starter/greeter-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/com/baeldung/greeter/autoconfigure/GreeterAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: Thank you – I've been working in a separate project and forgot that annotation. It still errs, but it's a _better_ error: "Field greeter in com.example.app.StarterApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.starter.Greeter' that could not be found."

Comment: Why are you trying to autoconfigure event-starter. Unless you are a framework developer I would avoid that. It is much easier to require clients to define the beans explicitly. I have worked with Spring boot for 10 years, and autoconfiguring is a lot of magic  both for the maintainer and every developer using you lib.

Comment: Also the project does not build after checkout, did you try it on a clean checkout? This is the error I get in Intellij
```A problem occurred configuring project ':application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':application:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1.
```

Comment: Thanks @KlausGroenbaek - strictly for the reason that it has been prominently mentioned in several tutorials. To be frank, the pattern that you are suggesting seems simpler. Apart from the “magic” is there anything about auto configure that makes it a bad fit for Spring? I’m not able to repro the second issue. The project built for me on a clean checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed a commit to the demo that fixes this issue, but in summary:

- The required bean wasn't being picked up by Spring it was in a discrete package.
- Adding `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = “com.example”)` where `com.example` is the parent package of both the starter AND the application fixed the problem. Conceivably, this could also be the neighbouring package directly.
- A command from the demo starter bean gets picked up, run in the application, and output to the logs.